# Cannot access to the Ubuntu after upgrade

Tags: grub2, grubrescue

I Downloaded updates and after restarting the computer, a message appeared saying

```
GNU GRUB Version 2.02~ beta 2-9 

Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB 
lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible 
device or file completions.

grub>_
```

I've read that you can use the boot repair, but how if I cannot access the operative system, Ubuntu is the only operating system in the computer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do that using a live ubuntu disk while mounting your active partition and then reinstalling grub using the live disk.

Answer (score 0):

**Simple way:** Make a Ubuntu live USB.

**Hard way:** Try this GRUB command to boot your Ubuntu.

```
grub> linux  (hd0,1)/boot/vmlinuz-xxx root=/dev/sdax
grub> initrd (hd0,1)/boot/initrd.img-xxx
grub> boot
```

After booting, you can use Boot Repair to fix GRUB.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more partitions on your computer, try doing `ls` then do `ls (hdX,Y)` on the things you saw on the `ls` command. If you see folders like 'boot', 'etc', 'root', that's probably your Ubuntu partition. Now execute the following commands to manually boot:

```
set root='(hdX,Y)'
linux /boot/vmlinuz-xxx root=/dev/sdXY
initrd /boot/initrd.img-xxx
boot
```

/dev/sdaXY depends on what (hdX,Y) is. If (hdX,Y) is (hd0,1) then you will have to set it to /dev/sda1, if it's (hd1,2) it will be /dev/sdb2.
After you boot to Ubuntu, login and open a terminal and try typing this:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Now you should reboot. If this doesn't fix grub, try re-installing it instead. Also re-install it on the device you already have grub.

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sdX             #Use what X was in the manual boot
sudo update-grub
```

Now reboot. This should re-install your grub and should fix your problem.